# How to correctly use network stream to get data?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, networkstream

I have an app communicates with industry machines through TCP/IP protocol.
It should come out something after I send an command to the machine's end point.
However, though I have implemented it with the way that Microsoft document shows,
my app never reads the data from the network stream.

Here is the code:

```
//The tcp client has been connected here.
if (client.Connected)
{
    var stream = client.GetStream();

    if (stream.CanWrite)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("010000000004");

        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        stream.Flush();
    }


    while(stream.DataAvailable is false) //keep sleeping when the data is not available
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }//The loop will be endless

    if (stream.CanRead) //I can't get to this step
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);

        var result = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I want to get the message from the machine so that I can interact with it.

Comment: Outside that I wouldn't recommend spin-waiting and prefer async API instead, it's hard to tell why this is happening. Are you _sure_ you sent _something_ and if so, the _right thing_? And there _should_ be an answer waiting (i.e. the machine answered indeed)?

Comment: Maybe you can setup a fake machine (=> software that emulates the machine's expected answers) for debugging?

Comment: @Fildor Ok, Let me check if the machine actually sent something back and it was the connection method that caused this problem. Thanks a lot.